# jquery find next image after the clicked instance

Tags: jquery, image, find, jquery-selectors, gallery

I'm trying to set up an image gallery where you can click a thumb and from that you can then use next and prev buttons. My issue is the user can initially click any image which I need to detect and the workout which the next or previous image will be and replace the display src with the src of the next image. I'm only trying to get the next button working first as the previous will work on the same principle. I have been trying to use the .next() but its really got me baffled.

Any help with this would be great.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c9Jkv/23/) of what I have and below is the jquery I've written, the problem is the bottom bit for the next button:

```
var numImgs = $('div.locationGallery .polaroidImage').length;
var prevImages = $('.polaroidImage').prevAll().length;
var thisImage;
var imageClicked;
var nextImage;
var nextImage;

$('.polaroidImage').click(function(){
    var prevImages = $(this.parentNode).prevAll().find('.polaroidImage').length;
    if(prevImages > 0){
        $('.prev').show();
    }else{
        $('.prev').hide();
    }
    if(prevImages == (numImgs - 1)){
        $('.next').hide();
    }else{
        $('.next').show();
    }
});

$(".thumb").click(function(){
      imageClicked = '';
      imageClicked = $(this).attr('src');
    $(".imageDisplay").find('img').remove();
    $(".imageDisplay").append("<img src='"+imageClicked+"' />")
});

$('.next').click(function(){
    nextImage = $('.imageContainer').next('img').attr('src');
    alert(nextImage);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example with working prev and next buttons: http://jsfiddle.net/8FMsH/1/
On thumb click you need to save the current image:

```
$(".thumb").click(function(){
  imageClicked = $(this);
  $(".imageDisplay").find('img').remove();
  $(".imageDisplay").append("<img src='"+imageClicked.attr('src')+"' />")
});

$('.next').click(function(){
 imageClicked.closest('.imageContainer').next().find('img').trigger('click');
});

$('.prev').click(function(){
 imageClicked.closest('.imageContainer').prev().find('img').trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the current image on click:

```
thisImage = $(this).closest('.imageContainer');
```

Then change the code on the next-click to this:

```
nextImage = thisImage.next().find('.thumb').attr('src');
```

See the example at http://jsfiddle.net/c9Jkv/24/

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your code by setting adding a class of `selected` onto the currently selected image and using that to "find" the next thumb.

http://jsfiddle.net/c9Jkv/25/

This seems quite contrived though, and it might be a bit easier if you just maintained some kind of data structure, e.g. an array or object or something which might make it a bit easier, rather than relying on the DOM to do everything.

Comment: The issue I have is this needs to work across hundreds of hard coded pages so I have very little to work with and this was pretty much the only way I could think of getting this to work without changing the structure of hundreds of pages

Comment: This doesn't require changing any source code. There's about 3 lines added to the jQuery which does everything for you. :)

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest using [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) or [Shadowbox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/index.html)

Comment: Also I mentioned in previous comments why I cant just use a pluggin