# Can't show next and previous all images from image unorderlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**First of all**, I am trying to show the first image from the unordered list images by default inside the first col-md-6 class="showimagediv" div tag. But I can't show it.

**Secondly**, I am trying to show next and previous all images from the ul li image list but if I click a single image from ul li images then showing image inside the first col-md-6 class="showimagediv" div tag, after that, if I click next the next images are not showing inside the first col-md-6 later, if I click prev the previous images are not showing inside the first col-md-6. Is there anyone who can solve it. Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {        
    $('.drag_drop_image').click(function(){
        $('.drag_drop_image').removeClass('clicked');
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    });
    $('.showimagediv').show();
    $('.drag_drop_image').on('click', function() {
        var img = $('<img />', {src : this.src,'class': 'fullImage'});
        $('.showimagediv').html(img).show();
    });

    $('.next').click(function(){
        if(!$(".clicked").is(".drag_drop_image:last")){
            $('.clicked').next().click();
        }else{
            $('.drag_drop_image:first').next().click();
        }
    });
    $('.prev').click(function(){
        if(!$(".clicked").is(".drag_drop_image:first")) {
            $('.clicked').prev().click();
        }else{
            $('.drag_drop_image:last').next().click();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.image-content{
position: relative;
display: block;
padding: 0;
}
.drag_drop_image {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 120px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
.ebay-image-wrap{
    padding: 0;
}
.ebay-image-wrap li{
    list-style: none;
}

.fullImage{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.main_image_show{
    position: relative;
}
.showimagediv {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 474px;
}
.clicked {
    outline: 2px solid #ccc;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.prev{
    position: absolute;
    top: 235px;
    background-color: thistle;
    padding: 5px;
}
.next{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 209px;
    background-color: thistle;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="padding:0;border: 1px solid #ccc">
        <div class="main_image_show">
            <a href="#p" class="prev">Prev</a>
            <div class="showimagediv">

            </div>
            <a href="#n" class="next">Next</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="padding:0;">
        <ul class="d-flex flex-wrap ebay-image-wrap">
            <li class="image-content">
                <img class="drag_drop_image clicked" src="https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/mdc/9558ac1034c99bd01ec60450e2bb4563.jpg" >
            </li>
            <li class="image-content">
                <img class="drag_drop_image" src="https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/92d708bbb8d153475993f7537f6b1c1d.jpg" >
            </li>
            <li class="image-content">
                <img class="drag_drop_image" src="https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/a5718f0aee97b1b280c47bf02620ef60.jpg" >
            </li>
            <li class="image-content">
                <img class="drag_drop_image" src="https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/original/b80aadadbaadbc1db27e692a5e6db52d.jpg" >
            </li>
            <li class="image-content">
                <img class="drag_drop_image" src="https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/68b7ca7375dfa5ea42556653bff77157.jpg" >
            </li>
            <li class="image-content">
                <img class="drag_drop_image" src="https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/mdc/d1b1d7ccca27fcbee8465441cfb08d62.jpg" >
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous and Next is working.  Good Luck

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {   

    function ShowFirstDefaultImage()
    {
        var firstDefaultImageSrc = $('.drag_drop_image:first').attr('src');
        var firstDefaultImage = $('<img />', {src : firstDefaultImageSrc,'class': 'fullImage'});
         $('.showimagediv').html(firstDefaultImage).show();
    }
  
    ShowFirstDefaultImage();

    $('.drag_drop_image').click(function(){
        $('.drag_drop_image').removeClass('clicked');
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    });
    $('.showimagediv').show();
    $('.drag_drop_image').on('click', function() {
        var img = $('<img />', {src : this.src,'class': 'fullImage'});
        $('.showimagediv').html(img).show();
    });

    $('.next').click(function(){
    
     
        if(!$(".clicked").is(".drag_drop_image:last")){
        
          var $first = $('li:first', 'ul'),
          $last = $('li:last', 'ul');
          var $next, $selected = $(".clicked");
          $next = $selected.next('li').length ? $selected.next('li') : $first;

          $selected.removeClass("clicked");
          $next.addClass('clicked');     
    
          //console.log($next.find('img').attr('src'));
          var imgSrc = $next.find('img').attr('src');
          var img = $next.find('img');
          var img = $('<img />', {src : imgSrc,'class': 'fullImage'});
        
         $('.showimagediv').html(img).show();
           
        }
    });
    $('.prev').click(function(){
    
        if(!$(".clicked").is(".drag_drop_image:first")) {
        
            var $first = $('li:first', 'ul'),
            $last = $('li:last', 'ul');
          
            var $prev, $selected = $(".clicked");
            $prev = $selected.prev('li').length ? $selected.prev('li') : $last;
            $selected.removeClass("clicked");
            $prev.addClass('clicked');
    
            //console.log($prev.find('img').attr('src'));
            var imgSrc = $prev.find('img').attr('src');
            var img = $prev.find('img');
            var img = $('<img />', {src : imgSrc,'class': 'fullImage'});

            $('.showimagediv').html(img).show();
         
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.image-content{
position: relative;
display: block;
padding: 0;
}
.drag_drop_image {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 120px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
.ebay-image-wrap{
    padding: 0;
}
.ebay-image-wrap li{
    list-style: none;
}

.fullImage{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.main_image_show{
    position: relative;
}
.showimagediv {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 474px;
}
.clicked {
    outline: 2px solid #ccc;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.prev{
    position: absolute;
    top: 235px;
    background-color: thistle;
    padding: 5px;
}
.next{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 209px;
    background-color: thistle;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="padding:0;border: 1px solid #ccc">
        <div class="main_image_show">
            <a href="#p" class="prev">Prev</a>
            <div class="showimagediv">

            </div>
            <a href="#n" class="next">Next</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="padding:0;">
        <ul class="d-flex flex-wrap ebay-image-wrap">
            <li class="image-content">
                <img class="drag_drop_image clicked" src="https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/mdc/9558ac1034c99bd01ec60450e2bb4563.jpg" >
            </li>
            <li class="image-content">
                <img class="drag_drop_image" src="https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/92d708bbb8d153475993f7537f6b1c1d.jpg" >
            </li>
            <li class="image-content">
                <img class="drag_drop_image" src="https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/a5718f0aee97b1b280c47bf02620ef60.jpg" >
            </li>
            <li class="image-content">
                <img class="drag_drop_image" src="https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/original/b80aadadbaadbc1db27e692a5e6db52d.jpg" >
            </li>
            <li class="image-content">
                <img class="drag_drop_image" src="https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/68b7ca7375dfa5ea42556653bff77157.jpg" >
            </li>
            <li class="image-content">
                <img class="drag_drop_image" src="https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/mdc/d1b1d7ccca27fcbee8465441cfb08d62.jpg" >
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also check out the link below for more detail example.

https://webdesignerhut.com/create-a-simple-jquery-image-slider/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611694/jquery-find-next-image-after-the-clicked-instance